# Accessibility ALT tags for img's rendered by AMP's amp-youtube tag

Tags: html, youtube, accessibility, amp-html, alt

So I have an AMP page with some Youtube embeds using the documented amp-youtube tag.

My AMP code:

```
<amp-youtube data-videoid="XXPNAEoX70w" layout="responsive" width="480" height="270"></amp-youtube>
```

Rendered child code:

```
<div class="ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/XXPNAEoX70w/maxresdefault.webp&quot;);"></div>
```

A background image is automatically rendered through the AMP js without an ALT tag that hurts Google's accessibility score ironically.

Adding an alt tag to parent items doesn't work so I'm kind of stumped at how to resolve this in the interim of Google getting their act together.

I already posted an issue on the AMP-HTML git repo. UPDATE: This issue was merged with existing issue. Not looking to be resolved anytime soon but I'll keep watching it. Until then I'm hoping/waiting for a work-around to improve accessibility and SEO.

Clever ideas?

Comment: You might like to post this as a issue in their [GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) to get an official answer whether this is a bug or an expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Rebot I did just so.